# How should plural English product names (ending with a consonant) be written in Spanish?

Tags: plurales

Given a product name like "MyThing", (where the name ends in a consonant) how should the plural "MyThings" be translated in Spanish?  I would think it should be simply "Los MyThing". Writing "Los MyThings" looks funny to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plurals of loan words](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2241/plurals-of-loan-words)

Comment: @walen - You convinced me it's not a duplicate.  I invite you to upvote the question with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frecuentemente lo que uno oye es el nombre común del producto (en plural) seguido del nombre de la marca, lo cual puede ser escrito en cualquier idioma.

Ejemplos:

- Los carros Ford
- Los cereales Kellogg's
- Los pianos Steinway

A veces, también se ve la inclusión de la palabra "de" (ejemplo: *los pianos de Steinway*).

Comment: ¡Gracias, señor!

Comment: Una pregunta seguimiento - ¿se escribe "más de 100 MyThing" y no "más de 100 MyThings"?

Comment: Si no es  posible (o no es práctico) hacer plural el nombre común, entonces, sí, se puede hacer plural el nombre de marca y usarlo como cualquier otro nombre.  En esos casos, es ordinario agregar una -s (en lugar de -es) aunque la palabra se termine en consonante (por ejemplo: "Los Fords son mejores que los Chevrolets").